# zapier magento2.1.11 authentication gets lost

Tags: magento, magento2, zapier, magento2.1

I setup a user role that has (currently) simply all resources.
I setup a user that has this role.
I authenticate with the user credentials (user and password, no store code) in zapier to create a connected magento2 account.

After some time my zap does not work anymore because the connected account cannot access my magento anymore.
I can just hit reconnect in zapier enter the same credentials as above and it works again.
But after some time it again does not work.

Looking at the magento documentation this is because custom and admin accounts expire after 1 or 4 hours.
Reading the documentation I would need an integration to have unlimited access.
But in zapier I cannot enter tokens or anything.

So I really wonder how I would set this up. If it is possible.
Or is just zapiers integration borked?

What is strange though is that this behavior began after upgrading to Magento version 2.1.11.
Other 2.1.x versions before did not have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That's a known bug on our end. In the meantime, you can override this via Configuration > Services > OAuth > Access Token Expiration

[image]

Comment: Hi David, thanks for replying. Any timely aspect as to when this will be fixed?

Comment: Since there's a solid workaround it hasn't been prioritized too heavily. We do track user requests volume to help choose what gets slotted in though. If you provide me with an email, I can put you on the list to vote and be notified when the issue is resolved. You can also write in to support @ zapier if you don't want to post your email here and they'll take care of you.

Comment: Not so far, no. Given that there's a workaround, it hasn't been prioritized on our end. Going forward, emailing support will be a better way to get information about this request.